# how to add a condition of comparing two fields of the model itself in Django model query

Tags: python, django, django-models

As mentioned by the title, in Django:

Say I have a model name QuestionRecord, with two fields: `full_score` and `actual_score`. 
I want to realize the SQL:

```
select * from QuestionRecord as QR where QR.full_score!=QR.actual_score.
```

Maybe using raw sql is OK, but I want to implement it like this:

```
class QuestionRecord_QuerySet(models.query.QuerySet):
    def incorrect(self):# Find out those whose full_score and actual_score are not equal
        return self.filter(...) # **What should I write here??**

class QuestionRecord_Manager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return QuestionRecord_QuerySet(self.model)

class QuestionRecord(models.Model):
    objects = QuestionRecord_Manager()
```

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 6):

Sure, that's what the ["`F`" object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#query-expressions) is for!

```
from django.db.models import F

# snip

    return self.exclude(full_score = F('actual_score'))
```

---

Use `QuerySet.exclude` here, as you want to not get the results that match.

If you really want to use `QuerySet.filter`, you can use a negated ["`Q`" object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#django.db.models.Q): `self.filter(~Q(full_score = F('actual_score')))`.